# How to search text using MATCH...AGAINST query?

Tags: mysql

**Table**

```
id    name
---  ------
1    chinu
2    sanjib
3    chinmay
```

**My MYSQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('chi' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

In above query i am getting `0` record.

My output will be coming

```
1   chinu
3   chinmay
```

How to get my actual record using MATCH...AGAINST query?

***EDIT*** - If i am searching `chinu` instead of chi i am getting 1 record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an asterisk to the 'chi' to indicate that the query should match against all that contain the string and not just the string itself. Just using the string 'chi' will only match exactly 'chi' for example.

change your query to read

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('chi*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and you should get the results you expect.

Comment: +1 . . . This is the right answer.  I'm leaving my answer because it might also prove helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `+` sign:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+chi' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Or if it is an exact phrase, use double quotes to surround the string:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"chi"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the first to admit that this is not easy to find.  MySQL full text search uses a system variable called `ft_min_word_length`.  The default value is 4, as shown [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len).

Because you are searching for a 3-character word, it is not being indexed.  Hence it is not found.

More information is available in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) on fine tuning the search.  But the basic idea is that you need to change the value of the parameter and rebuild the index.

For your particular query, though, you just need to include wildcards, as explained in other answers.